# Turtle and QPython

Tags: turtle-graphics, qpython

I have been playing with basic Python(2.3) on my PC (which has Windows 8 OS) for awhile, but my PC broke and I now just have my Android Kitkat tablet.

I downloaded Qpython and have been using that, but when I try to import and start turtle - in the way I have always done on my PC, it just runs:

```
ImportError : No module named turtle
```

Is there another way to run turtle on QPython? Or is turtle not able to run on Android?

Answer (score 0):

Turtle works with tkinter but tkinter isn't working on mobile device. You may use kivy to do so and kivy is cross-plateform for your android and also your PC. I've never use it but I'm going to get a try. I think it may solve your problem.